# How do I use Grand Central Dispatch to kick off one asynchronous call?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

I want to have one call occur asynchronously, the equivalent of:

`doThisInASecondThreadThenHaveThisThreadDisappear:@selector(myMethod);`

What is the Grand Central Dispatch call to accomplish this?  I'm new to it and I get lost with all the complex stuff with queueing.  I understand things that can be achieved with that, but for this simple case (that I currently care about) I'm just lost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queueName", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
    // code to execute here
});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Or if you need to use the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // code to execute here
});
```

Comment: You can also use `dispatch_get_global_queue` to get one of the global concurrent queues instead of creating a queue. This can be preferable since you don't have to do any memory management.

Comment: @zneak can you elaborate on exactly what they'd look like?

Comment: `dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick code example

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);    
dispatch_async(queue, ^{   
    // Stuff to do on another thread
    // Mostly heavy calculations

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Stuff to do on main thread
        // Mostly UI stuff
    });                    
});
```

Comment: Global queues don't have to be released, the last call is a nop (and you would be missing a pairing dispatch_retain anyway in pedantic mode).